# $\sum\sin(\frac{k\pi}{4})$ absolute convergent, conditional convergent,divergent?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Would the following be abs convergent, conditional convergent or divergent.

$\sum\sin(\frac{k\pi}{4})$

I know sin(x) is between $-1<x<1$

y=sin(x) is oscillating would it be $(-1)^n$

Comment: What is $k$? $1$ to $\infty$? Only odd integers? Only evens?

Comment: I think it is from 1 to infinity

Comment: A series can only be convergent if its general term converges to 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry about the old answer, that was just garbage.

The real answer is that it's not convergent. You can try grouping them in terms of $8$ like I had done, but the problem is that, because it ends at $\infty$, you don't have a point to end at. That means the answer could be the same as any of the following eight:

$\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^1 \sin \left(\frac{k \pi}{4}\right) = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$.

$\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^2 \sin \left(\frac{k \pi}{4}\right) = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} + 1$.

$\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^3 \sin \left(\frac{k \pi}{4}\right) = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$.

$\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^4 \sin \left(\frac{k \pi}{4}\right) = 0$.

$\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^5 \sin \left(\frac{k \pi}{4}\right) = -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$.

$\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^6 \sin \left(\frac{k \pi}{4}\right) = -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} - 1$.

$\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^7 \sin \left(\frac{k \pi}{4}\right) = -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$.

$\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^8 \sin \left(\frac{k \pi}{4}\right) = 0$.

Because they're different, and because you have no sure way of determining which is the right answer, the answer is that the series does not converge.

---

This is actually a classic problem of trying to find the sum of an alternating series. Let's take a similar problem, where you're trying to find the answer to $$1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + \cdots$$ (This is called [Grandi's Series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grandi%27s_series), btw.)

There are multiple answers, depending on how you group them. You can group them as $(1-1) + (1-1) + \cdots = 0 + 0 + \cdots = 0$, as $1 + (-1 + 1) + (-1 + 1) + \cdots = 1 + 0 + 0 + \cdots = 1$, or even as $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2} + \left(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2}\right) + \left(-\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\right) + \cdots = \frac{1}{2} + 0 + 0 + \cdots = \frac{1}{2}$. Since there's no "right" way of doing this, the answer is DNE. Hence, it does not converge.

Comment: Potentially misleading hint, isn't it?

Comment: D'oh! Sorry, I just realized the flaw in that argument.

Comment: yes being cyclic there is a possibility that it converges but I cannot find the ak part that is different from the rest of the cylic sum.

Answer (score 1):

sin(kπ/4)  is not converge sequence

so sigma(sin(kπ/4)) has not converge condition

Comment: +1 You can be even sharper: $\;\left\{\sin\frac{k\pi}4\right\}\;$ does not coverge *to zero* and thus its series can't converge.